# Calling $this->modelname->methodname() with modelname as a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, model

I am trying to create a generic method that will be able to save all data from different models depending on which "entity" I am handling in the code. As you can see below, I have a variable $entity on which I want decide loading a model and then after that calling a method from it.

The two commented lines in my example are showing what I am trying to achieve, but they are not working. The uncommented (non-dynamic) line `$this->companylocation_model->save(...)` is working fine.

The commented experiment gives this error: `call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class '$this-&gt;companylocation_model' not found`. strange to me, because I am loading that model in the line before it.

I have also tried escaping the > with a backslash but that also doesn't work.

```
public function submit($entity) // $entity is set to companylocation during method call
{
    $filledEntityObject = $this->getEntityDataFromForm($entity);
    $this->load->model($entity . '_model');
    $this->companylocation_model->save($filledEntityObject, $filledEntityObject->id);

    //call_user_func(array('$this->' . $entity . '_model', 'save'), $filledEntityObject, $filledEntityObject->id);
    //call_user_func('$this->' . $entity . '_model->save', $filledEntityObject, $filledEntityObject->id);
...
```

Expected result is simply being able to call the `save` method from the model with two parameters in a dynamic way.

Comment: Not tried is but does `$this->{$entity . '_model'}->save(...)` (with the correct parameters) work? (For older versions you may need to use `$name = $entity . '_model';` and  `$this->$name->save(...)` - again not sure)

Comment: Thank you @NigelRen! `$this->{$entity . '_model'}->save($filledEntityObject, $filledEntityObject->id)` did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `call_user_func` you can build the name using the parts directly into the call...

```
$this->{$entity . '_model'}->save(...)
```